# vlookup with string as variable

Tags: excel

I've searched the forum and found part of answers, but still can't figure it out.

I have the following vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8, '[CONSO_SISO FY15_ME (without TUR-ISR)_BTQ.xlsx]**Abu Shakra**'!$A$13:$N$563, 3, FALSE)
```

'Abu Shakra' is the name of a sheet in another file.
I have a drop down list with all the sheet names and I would like to be able to change the formula when a different name is chosen from the list.

I tried using `=indirect()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should definitely use `INDIRECT()`. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8, INDIRECT("'[CONSO_SISO FY15_ME (without TUR-ISR)_BTQ.xlsx]"&A1&"'!$A$13:$N$563"), 3, FALSE)
```

Where `A1` is cell with your sheet name.

Comment: @user3756472 - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Be sure and click on "Accept" for this answer.